# Use-Case Diagram Boolean Situation

Tags: oop, uml, use-case-diagram

Is there a boolean situation in use case diagram? If not this else do this? here is my example:
[image]

The user doesn't need to know that we create him a user, all happens in the background. So it's like a client application that communicate with another server.
If the user already exists in the new server, just process the add to cart, otherwise, create a user for that specific user on the other server.

EDIT:

Thanks to Thomas Kilian advice's, this should be the right answer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UCs have a couple of flaws (because you are trying functional decomposition and not synthesis; read Bittner/Spence).

- Showing a boundary as bubble is wrong. P. 642 of UML 2.5.1:

  > Note also that the subject rectangle does not imply that the subject classifier owns the contained UseCases, but merely that the UseCases apply to that classifier. In particular, there is scope for confusion between a UseCase appearing visually contained in a boundary **rectangle** representing a Classifier that is its subject, and appearing visually contained in a compartment of a Classifier that is its owner (see Figure 18.9).
- `Add to cart` to `Validates user` (which should be `Validate user`) needs to be a `- ->` `<<includes>>` relation rather than an association.
- `Validate user` including `Add to cart` does not seem to make sense. Adding an item to a cart is something completely different from a user validation.
- `Create user` (`s` deleted) should be an `<<extends>>` in the opposite direction. Add a constraint `{ only for new users }`.
- `Process add to cart` is no use case. It's a couple of steps in the `Add to cart` UC (which follow after user verification).

Comment: There's still room for discussion about the model, though. Unfortunately this can't go in the margin left here. Best is to take time with Bittner/Spence asap.

Comment: Yea, to be honest, the example I put up here is just random thing that came in my mind so I can learn how to do the boolean case(maybe not the perfect example). Bittner/Spence is a book?

Comment: Yes. Just google for it together with "use case". Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely have a look at it :)